# Array reduce function with async await

Tags: javascript, async-await

I'm trying to skip one object from an array objects based on a async operator. I've tried following cases, but getting a Type error.

Tried Method 1

```
newObjectArray = await Promise.all(objectAray.reduce(async (result, el) => {
  const asyncResult = await someAsyncTask(el);
  if (asyncResult) {
      result.push(newSavedFile);
  }
  return result;
}, []));
```

Tried Method 2

```
newObjectArray = await Promise.all(objectAray.reduce(async (prevPromise, el) => {
  const collection = await prevPromise;
  const asyncResult = await someAsyncTask(el);
  if (asyncResult) {
      prevPromise.push(newSavedFile);
  }

  collection.push(newSavedFile);
  return collection;
}, Promise.resolve([])));
```

Error

```
'TypeError: #<Promise> is not iterable',
'    at Function.all (<anonymous>)',
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is the desired output?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your first try, `result` is a promise as all `async` functions evaluate to a promise when called, so you have to `await result` before you can push to the array, and then you don't need the Promise.all:

```
 newObjectArray = await objectAray.reduce(async (result, el) => {
  const asyncResult = await someAsyncTask(el);
  if (asyncResult) {
    (await result).push(newSavedFile);
  }
  return result;
}, []);
```

But I'd guess that it is way faster to just filter afterwards:

```
 newObjectArray = (await Promise.all(objArray.map(someAsyncTask))).filter(el => el);
```

Comment: Isn't filter will cost on double iteration over the array.

Comment: @ankit yup bat that might cost you a few nanoseconds, while executing one `someAsyncTask` after another will take you much more. Just put a `Date.now()` before and after this, and see how both perform ...

Comment: thanks for your answer. Its not possible to use Promise.all() when I reduce to Object. So I love your answer which helped that purpose :) thank you!